# linked list php spl or custom?

Tags: php, list

I need to use a double linked list using PHP for my script so I dug on the web and found a very good one:

http://www.codediesel.com/algorithms/doubly-linked-list-in-php/

this one made me understand how it works, and how the elements are tied together etc...

Now, PHP has its own set of SPL functions for double linked lists, which makes it very easy but on the other hand, I have to trust what php do and I am also limited to what they have.

Should I use instead the one from PHP? Or should I use this code in the link and in case I want to customize it, can I easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use whatever is more appropriate for you, but here are some considerations:

- PHP SPL code is maintained and community-vetted, code from a random blog is typically not
- the `SplDoublyLinkedList` is already there, no extra code to maintain
- the `SplDoublyLinkedList` is only there if your PHP version is current
- you can `extend` and customize the `SplDoublyLinkedList` class to your liking
- the `SplDoublyLinkedList` *may* be faster, since it's native code (I guess); benchmark if this an important factor to you